# Ionic Framework: clicking a button to add elements to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

For an Ionic app project, I created a json file that stores some event data. This file will later be downloaded within the application and stored locally on the device/ but might be updated to provide new data.

I displayed the data on the artist page with a ng-repeat directive. The problem I am facing is the following: Everytime when the user clicks the plus button on one of the elements, the element is supposed to be displayed on another page (kind of favorite page). What can be a solution to this problem?

HTML

```
  <ion-item
          ng-repeat='item in artists | filter: query' class="artist-box">
              <div class ="info-box-purple" >
                  <div class = "info-box-text">
                      <span>{{item.day | Saturday}}<br>{{item.time}}<br>{{item.stage}}</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <a href="#/app/artists/{{item.shortname}}">
                  <h3 class="artist-title"><span>{{item.name}}</span></h3>
                  <div class="item image item-image">
                      <img ng-src="img/artists/{{item.shortname}}.jpg" alt="{{item.name}} Photo"/>
                  </div>
              </a>
              <div><button class="add-button button button-royal ion-plus"></button></div>

          </ion-item>
```

Controller (link between html and controller on separate page)

```
   .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state){
        $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.artists = data;
            $scope.pickedartist = $state.params.bandId;
        });
    }

])
```

Format of JSON file

```
[
    {
        "festival" : "festival 1",
        "day" : "Friday",
        "time" : "17:00",
        "stage" : "Stage 1",
        "name" : "Balkan Beat Box",
        "shortname" : "Balkan_Beat_Box",
        "bio" : "Balkan Beat Box (BBB) is an Israeli musical group founded by Tamir Muskat, Ori Kaplan and now including Tomer Yosef as a core member. The group plays Mediterranean-influenced music that incorporates Jewish, Eastern Europe (mainly Balkan) and Middle Eastern traditions, Gypsy punk, reggae and electronica. As a musical unit they often collaborate with a host of other musicians both in the studio as well as live.",
        "facebook" : "https://www.facebook.com/balkanbeatbox",
        "schedule" : "+"

    },{
        "festival" : "festival 1",
        "day" : "Friday",
        "time" : "18:00",
        "stage" : "Stage 2",
        "name" : "Blick Bassy",
        "shortname" : "Blick_Bassy",
        "bio" : "Born in 1974, singer, songwriter, guitarist and percussionist Blick Bassy grew up with 20 siblings in Cameroon’s capital Yaoundé, a city where people from all parts of the country come together, and the first languages are French and English. Bassy says: “People in Yaoundé lose their traditions and culture rapidly because they don’t speak in their mother tongues with each other or their children. My family is part of the Bassa ethnic group, a nomad tribe that originally comes from Egypt and has descendents down in South Africa. But nowadays people stay in one place because they need visas to cross borders. The word ‘bassa’ means ‘people from the earth’.”",
        "schedule" : "+"
    },{
        "festival" : "festival 1",
        "day" : "Friday",
        "time" : "19:00",
        "stage" : "Stage 3",
        "name" : "Clueso",
        "shortname" : "Clueso",
        "bio" : "Thomas Hübner (born April 9, 1980), better known by his stage name Clueso (pronounced [klyˈzo]), is a German singer, rapper, songwriter and producer. Born in Erfurt, he started performing at the age of 15. His first album Text und Ton was released in 2001. In 2011, Clueso released his album An und für sich, which reached number 2 on the German Top 100. In 2016, he released his latest album Neuanfang, peaking at number 1 on the German Top 100. His music is notable for being a mix of hip hop, pop and electronic music, and sometimes reggae.",
        "schedule" : "-"
    }]
```

Comment: you are confusing terms here.  Angular.copy can indeed copy one **object** to another **object**, but it has nothing to do with reading and writing the data from files.  Where are these files stored?  Angular can't write files to your server (at all), you'll probably need some sort of API to receive the data and do the writing on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification. I tried to generalize the problem to be more relevant to others, but basically I want to achieve the following: I have a file with some event data that is displayed to the user. When the user clicks "like" for one event, this event is supposed to be displayed on another page of the app. Since I already read here that Angular can't write files, I thought to overcome the problem with "copying". What could be a valid alternative?

Comment: right, so where is this file with the event data?  saying "when the user clicks, display on another page" is pretty broad, and doesn't tie directly to the idea that you would need to write anything to a file, so it's still not really clear what you are asking....

Comment: you can display data on a new page in angular without writing files, in other words.... Your question is sounding more and more like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  You should probably try to edit your question and ask about what you are trying to accomplish, rather than your possible solution that doesn't feel like it fits here.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I updated the question focusing on my problem only. The json file will be stored locally on the user's device, given  that it will  be still be possible to update it, but that's out of my scope right now. Hope this is not too amateurish.